# How do I configure SSL on IIS 6.0 FTP Server?

Tags: ssl, iis-6, ftp

I am using IIS 6 FTP server for the exchange of files through `System.Net.FtpWebRequest`.

I want to configure SSL on IIS 6.0's FTP server so that it will allow secure connections.

Is this possible, if so how do I do this?

Answer (score 2):

IIS 6 does not support FTP over SSL (FTPS), however IIS 7 (and 7.5) does.  If IIS 7 is not an option for you, you will most likely need to look at third party alternatives.

Here is information about IIS7:

http://learn.iis.net/page.aspx/310/what-is-new-for-microsoft-and-ftp-75/